# json api and json user api plugin is not working

Tags: php, json, wordpress, plugins

I want to create php restful api for wordpress for ultimate member plugin. please help me with it. please suggest me the exact procedure to login and register with the help of json user api and json api plugin of wordpress. now i have installed it and using this url to regster.

https://www.example.com/api/get_nonce/?controller=user&method=register

and returning this response

```
       {"status":"ok","controller":"user","method":"register","nonce":"5f1040eaf8"}
```

but its not storing to database. can you tell me why its happening so.

Comment: For passwords, have a look at the PHP [password API](http://php.net/password). Beyond that, I think your question is too broad.

Comment: @JonStirling actually i also used json user api plugin and getnonce to authenticate url request but its only producing nonce and not storing data to database..

Comment: for json user api. i am using this url to register https://www.nuvemsonora.com/api/get_nonce/?controller=user&method=register

Comment: I have no idea what your comments are trying to get at, nor what specific relevance they have to your question. I suggest editing your questing with something more concise than just adding comments.

Comment: can i create custom php retfull api for wordpress ultimate member plugin or i should have to use any plugin like json api @JonStirling ?

Comment: Thanks for your help @JonStirling. I have edited my question now can you help with it.

Answer (score 0):

you made it the right way for the first step..

you got the `nonce` value, you can now pass it to registration url and provide the required info:

```
http://example.com/api/user/register/?insecure=cool" +
                                    "&username=" + username + "&user_pass=" + password +
                                    "&first_name=" + firstname + "&last_name=" + lastname +
                                    "&email=" + email +
                                    "&nonce=" + nonce +
                                    "&display_name=" + displayName
```

Comment: When i tried this using axios, I get  `"Your 'nonce' value was incorrect. Use the 'get_nonce' API method."` error. But when I paste this URL to the browser, it can successfully add the user. What am I missing?

Comment: @TsukimotoMitsumasa  yes, you should do another request to `get_nonce` first to get the value of `nonce` to pass it to this request mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @TsukimotoMitsumasa, so call this `https://www.example.com/api/get_nonce/?controller=user&method=register` first, to get `nonce` value. and then do the request in the answer with the `nonce` value

Answer (score 0):

To login , you need authentication cookie , this authentication cookie will verify the validity of the user credentials( user name and password) you have passed . So to get authentication cookie , try this link ->http://www.example.com/api/user/generate_auth_cookie/?insecure=cool&username=USER_NAME&password=USER_PASSWORD

. From there you can have the result json object will have some data one of it is authentication cookie , cookie_name and status string - if status string is "ok" user credentials are valid so you can allow user to login otherwise dont allow .

Registration process require a nonce with a json api controller "user" and method "create_user" . Generate a nonce and then use it to create a new user as shown in the link by @Biskrem above except you can add notify parameter with value both

Comment: hello @emm-jk , I successfully get the authentication cookie, but I am confused on how to use it. i have an axios.get() call to get the authentication cookie, and it was a success but how do I use it to successfully call the create_user endpoint. In my case, it is still showing `"Your 'nonce' value was incorrect. Use the 'get_nonce' API method."`.